# MySQL get rows with time interval

Tags: mysql, sql, time, intervals

I have a table with some columns where one column has timestamp where data is created.
Suppose following is a table.

```
id | val | time
---+-----+--------------------
1  |  1  |2016-07-02 03:31:31
1  |  2  |2016-07-02 03:32:32
1  |  2  |2016-07-02 03:33:33
1  |  3  |2016-07-02 03:33:34
1  |  4  |2016-07-02 03:41:31
1  |  5  |2016-07-02 03:41:32
1  |  5  |2016-07-02 03:46:33
1  |  6  |2016-07-02 03:47:34
```

On an average of every one second, one entry goes to that table. This is too much data to show on UI. I want data to be consolidated for every 10 minutes.

i.e. only two row should come as result. The value of column `val` can be anything, it is ok if the `val` is any one of them or the average of them.

Desired output (any of three)

```
id | val | time
---+-----+--------------------
1  |  1  |2016-07-02 03:3X:XX
1  |  4  |2016-07-02 03:4X:XX
```

OR

```
id | val | time
---+-----+--------------------
1  |  2  |2016-07-02 03:3X:XX
1  |  5  |2016-07-02 03:4X:XX
```

OR

```
id | val | time
---+-----+--------------------
1  |  3  |2016-07-02 03:3X:XX
1  |  6  |2016-07-02 03:4X:XX
```

Is there a way to make that 10 minutes as dynamic parameters? (static is ok for start)

*EDIT*
Including my comment here: I am using hibernate, so preference is hibernate. But if that does not work then we only have option with MySQL native. There is no criteria of last X rows, I want all the rows for particular id and between particular date. It's just that i want less rows with 10 mins of interval.

Comment: mysql raw, or hibernate? You have a hibernate question going elsewhere. Also, be clear on what spits out from the query, such as the last X rows (10 min intervals) from `now()` backwards or something. Someone has to actually code this thing, and would like to get it right the first time

Comment: I am using hibernate, so preference is hibernate. But if that does not work then we only have option with MySQL native.
There is no criteria of last X rows, I want all the rows for particular id and between particular  date. It's just that i want less rows with 10 mins of interval. Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: Ok, so you want to pass two `datetimes` and have 10 minute intervals then. I can do that in non-hibernate, but as it is 2am, I am out of steam.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give your expected result.

> MySQL syntax

```
DROP TABLE TEMP_TEST;
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TEST(ID INT,VAL INT,TIME DATETIME);

INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST VALUES
(1,1,'2016-07-02 03:31:31'),
(1,2,'2016-07-02 03:32:32'),
(1,2,'2016-07-02 03:33:33'),
(1,3,'2016-07-02 03:33:34'),
(1,4,'2016-07-02 03:41:31'),
(1,5,'2016-07-02 03:41:32'),
(1,5,'2016-07-02 03:46:33'),
(1,6,'2016-07-02 03:47:34'),
(1,6,'2016-07-02 03:51:34');


SELECT @INTERVAL := 10, @PREVIOUS_TIME := (select time from TEMP_TEST LIMIT  1);
SELECT TIME,
@INTERVAL ,
@PREVIOUS_TIME,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,@PREVIOUS_TIME,TIME) AS DIFF_INTERVAL,
  (CASE
    WHEN ((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,@PREVIOUS_TIME,TEMP_TEST.TIME))%@INTERVAL)=0 THEN "TRUE"
    ELSE "FALSE"
  END) AS VALID
from TEMP_TEST;
```

> SQL Server syntax

```
DROP TABLE #TEMP_TEST;
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TEST(ID INT,VAL INT,TIME DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_TEST VALUES
(1,1,'2016-07-02 03:31:31'),
(1,2,'2016-07-02 03:32:32'),
(1,2,'2016-07-02 03:33:33'),
(1,3,'2016-07-02 03:33:34'),
(1,4,'2016-07-02 03:41:31'),
(1,5,'2016-07-02 03:41:32'),
(1,5,'2016-07-02 03:46:33'),
(1,6,'2016-07-02 03:47:34'),
(1,6,'2016-07-02 03:51:34');


DECLARE @INTERVAL INT=10;
DECLARE @PREVIOUS_TIME DATETIME;
SELECT TOP 1 @PREVIOUS_TIME=TIME FROM #TEMP_TEST ORDER BY TIME

SELECT TIME,
@INTERVAL AS INTERVAL ,
@PREVIOUS_TIME AS PREVIOUS_TIME, 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@PREVIOUS_TIME,TIME) AS DIFF_INTERVAL,
CASE WHEN (((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@PREVIOUS_TIME,TIME))%@INTERVAL)=0) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS TRUE
FROM #TEMP_TEST
WHERE (CASE WHEN (((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@PREVIOUS_TIME,TIME))%@INTERVAL)=0) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END)='TRUE'
ORDER BY TIME
```

EDIT : Updated MySQL Syntax of query.